# Override POST, PATCH & DELETE methods

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

How do I override the POST, PATCH & DELETE methods for multiple ViewSets to allow me add a mandatory backend parameter?

Logic. Am building a multi-tenant app which has got a "tenant_id" in all the relevant tables. This tenant_id identifies the tenant and as such all requests must include this parent key to avoid users seeing/modifiying content that is not theirs.

For Get queries, I have created a custom filter backend which enables me to add a mandatory filter object to limit what a user can get

```
class CustomFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    """
    Filter that only allows users to see entries related to their tenant.
    """
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        tenant_id = get_tenant_id_from_token(request)
        return queryset.filter(is_deleted=False, tenant_id=tenant_id)
```

I have then added this filter to all ViewSet Classes via the `filter_backends = ()` option

Question is, is there a way to achieve the same for POST, PATCH, DELETE requests?

My current thinking is that one would override the `model.save` method for all models? But that won't take care of HTTP `DELETE` method.

**Transparent tenant_id**:

In the models, the tenant_id is of course mandatory. However, I don't want to force the web/mobile client to always provide the tenant_id since I can get it from the user's JWT token. i.e. tenant_id should be transparent to the web/mobile app.

**EDIT 2**

Issue is, I want to silently/quietly/behind-the-scenes add a `tenant_id` without the web/mobile app being aware. Meaning I don't want the apps using the API to send a `tenant_id` JSON key.

**Sample Model**

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    """
    Sample model
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class CustomFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
"""
Filter that only allows users to see entries related to their tenant.
"""
def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
    tenant_id = get_tenant_id_from_token(request)
    return queryset.filter(is_deleted=False, tenant_id=tenant_id)


class SampleViewSet(ListCreateRetrieveUpdateViewSet):
    """
    Sample viewset
    """
    serializer_class = SampleModelSerializer
    permission_classes = (HasPermission)
    queryset = SampleModel.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (CustomFilterBackend, )
```

By adding the filter_backends to all viewsets, all GET queries now include a tenant_id. So what I want is to achieve the same to all other HTTP methods especially POST and PATCH

From reading it seems like I have to override the serializers? Is it possible to do it in a DRY manner? So far I haven't figured out how to

The JWT where am getting the tenant_id has a Payload looking like this after creating a custom `jwt_payload_handler`:

```
{
  "exp": 1477069682,
  "is_superuser": true,
  "email": "test-email@gmail.com",
  "tenant_id": 1,  #THE TENANT ID
  "user_id": 1,
  "username": "test-email@gmail.com"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an [HiddenField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#advanced-field-defaults) and create a class that will fetch the tenant just like `CurrentUserDefault` does.

For example if you want to set the tenant of the currently logged in user (independently of how he is authenticated, token, session... ):

```
class CurrentTenantDefault(CurrentUserDefault):
    def __call__(self):
        current_user = super().__call__()
        return current_user.tenant
```

If you do not use Django authentication (you should !), have a look at the implementation of [CurrentUserDefault](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L266) to see how to get the tenant form the request (make sure to return a tenant instance, not its id, which may not work).

Maybe something like:

```
class CurrentTenantDefault():
    def set_context(self, serializer_field):
        request = serializer_field.context['request']
        tenant_id = get_tenant_id_from_token(request)
        self.tenant = Tenant.objects.get(pk=tenant_id)

    def __call__(self):
        return self.tenant
```

Then in the serializers, declare the hidden field like:

```
    tenant = serializers.HiddenField(default=CurrentTenantDefault())
```

**Note**: You should not declare the `ForeignKey` in your model with a name finishing with '_id' because when you instanciate your model, `instance.tenant` is a Tenant instance, not the tenant ID. Django does store the foreign key in tenant_id column but this is transparent and you do not need to care about it.

Comment: Am using Django's authentication. Also, the `ForeignKey` aren't declared using `_id` and I've corrected the sample model I'd given. In your suggestion, where would I place the `CurrentTenantDefault`? Also, the tenant identifier is to be fetched from the private section of the JWT token. Am using `django-rest-framework-jwt` and on login I'd added the tenant_id to the token. See example I've added to the question..

Comment: I usually keep it in the `serializers` module or when serializers are split in several module, in something like `serializers.core`. I have updated the answer with an example of `CurrentTenantDefault` using your `get_tenant_id_from_token` function.

Comment: Thank you sir. This works as expected and its simple to understand

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to figure out how an Id is passed to view, Your answer is simple. `Id is mostly passed to views through urls`. Try  `GET` request to your queryset with id as below.

```
api/url/endpoint/1
```

And 1 will be passed from urls to views by drf routers. Then based on the `http method`, which in your case is GET appropriate action is chosen. For instance, if you are calling aforementioned url using `GET,PUT,PATCH or DELETE` methods 1 is considered as `reference to Id of the object` and then an orm query is performed that can be

```
model.objects.get(id=1) #if request.method is GET
model.objects.get(id=1).delete() #if request.method is DELETE
model.objects.get(id=1) #if request.method is PATCH or PUT and then the fields of the corresponding object will be updated.
```

If you are passing a `POST` request to api endpoint, in general scenario model name will be identified through api endpoint and then a new object will be created using the params passed.

Now to answer the other part, ie what is returned. In most case drf return a `object of class Response` that can be used as `JSON` object by browsers as well as mobile devices. But these Responses wont be returned from methods like get() in scenarios that involve drf viewsets to follow an [mro](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). In those cases usually the last function, which in most cases is `render_to_response()` will be returning the response.

HTH

Comment: Am not looking for how an ID is passed. I've edited the question and provided more clarity. See if the question makes sense now.